# Viewport for embedded Unity in a web browser?

Tags: html, web, unity-game-engine

we are going to embed a Unity file into a webpage. However, we were asking ourself if there is some standard height in pixels for the unity animation, which can ensure that user doesn't have to scroll vertically. 
The target would be a common PC with Chrome, let's say. 1366x768 should be, then, the minimum requirement. So, considered the address bar and what is on the top of a browser like Chrome (normally), which is, in your experience the height of the viewport to be considered in this case as a good choice?

Thanks!
Fabio

Comment: This seems like it would apply to anything you'd put on a webpage and is not specific to Unity. Your best bet is to try a few different sizes and see what looks best.

Comment: Sure I will try... However, I am aware that there is no standard as browsers viewport can widely change. Just asking about what you would do or what you have done in similar situations...